# How to filter our products by tags in shopify using OR condition?

Tags: shopify, liquid

Filtering products by tags in Shopify is quite simple in case of a single tag or even with multiple tags but with AND condition. 
But How can I filter products in Shopify with OR condition?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is you can't using default liquid logic.

The long answer is you can use GraphQL, but that has limitations that may not fit your needs.

Your best approach will be to use a 3rd App for this, which is probably not the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no default Shopify logic to use tags with an OR condition in collection pages. But you can use it on the search page. So if, in your case, the default search page is not in use, you can convert it to your listing page using the below logic.

https://your-site.com/search?q=tag:size_xl+OR+size_m

So here it will show all products having the tag either "size_xl" or "size_m".